# Show Woocommerce demo store notice only on tuesdays

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to show the woocommerce store notice demo_store only when store is closed. This is every tuesday. I thought about first getting the date, then remove the action and re-add it on tuesdays. I would love to learn how to do this.

```
function is_store_closed() {
    
    // weekday[0] =  "Sunday";
    // weekday[1] = "Monday";
    // weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    // weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    // weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    // weekday[5] = "Friday";
    // weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    
         return (date('true', strtotime($date)) == 2);
    }    
    
    function conditional_store_notice() {
        // Remove default 'woocommerce_demo_store' notice
        remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'woocommerce_demo_store' );
    
        // Add back the woocommerce_demo_store' notice, but only if tuesday
        if ( ! is_store_closed() ) {
            add_action( 'wp_footer', 'woocommerce_demo_store' );
        }
    
    }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'conditional_store_notice' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove that html from filter, Ideally it removes the content from rendering.

```
function is_store_closed() {
    $timestamp = time();
    return ( date( 'w', $timestamp ) === '2' );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_demo_store', function( $html, $notice ){
    if( !is_store_closed() ){
        return '';
    }

    return $html;
}, 10, 2 );
```

This code remove Store notice content on other days of week.

Comment: I like this approach!

Comment: This is awesome!! thank you so much. One small question is there a way to also hide or add /* Desktop */
.woocommerce-demo-store {
    margin-top: 65px;
}

/* Mobile */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .woocommerce-demo-store {
        margin-top: 90px;
    }
} This because it will cover my header otherwise.

Comment: If you can share a link i think i can help you since this is css i have to look what is actual issue.

Comment: Thank you i create a temporary url. [link](https://www.temporary-url.com/107FBD)

Comment: so you want to add css so the store notice will not cover your header or what ?

Comment: Yes exactly i dont know how els to do it